# Longest increasing substring with gap

Tags: algorithm, substring, lis

I've encountered a problem specified as follows:

Let *A* be a sequence of positive integers.
Let *B* be a substring of *A*.
Let *C* be a sequence created by removing *B* from *A*.
For given *A*, find the length of the longest increasing (strictly) substring of *C*, where *B* can be chosen arbitrarily.

For example let *A = [3 2 5 7 1 2 8 1]*. If we set *B = [1 2]*, then *C = [3 2 5 7 8 1]* and its longest increasing substring is *[2 5 7 8]*, which length is 4. 4 is the answer since there exist no other *B* which would lead to a better solution.

I can't find an algorithm to solve the problem (in polynomial time, of course :) ), but I belive it would be some variation of the longest increasing subsequence problem.
Please help me to find a good algorithm or give me some hints or references.

Comment: No B would end up at better solution. Or you can say B should be empty for best solution. I think you understood or mentioned question incorrectly.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Substrings are generally considered to be continuous, which does lead to the best solution to the question as stated possibly necessarily involving a non-empty B.

Comment: Polynomial time? Do you mean linear time? You can brute force your way to a polynomial time (O(n^2) or O(n^3)?) solution. Unless this is actually about subsets (non-continuous) instead of substrings, in which case it seems identical to the longest increasing subsequence problem.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I misread. Its difficult to identify `substring` after `longest increasing` :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing a single iteration through the input array:

- Set up an array `smallest[n]`, where `smallest[i]` represents the smallest element which an increasing substring of length `i` can end with (e.g. if `smallest[3] = 5`, that means there's a substring of length 3 ending with a `5`, and there is no substring of length 3 ending with a `4`, otherwise `smallest[3]` will be `4`).

  We can keep track of the longest substring `i` so far, and simply replace `smallest[i]` if that element is bigger than the current element.

  An important notes about this array: the elements in this array will be in strictly increasing order, that is to say, if a substring of length `i` ending in element `x` exists in the array, there is no longer substring containing an element equal to or less than `x` (this is because the longer substring will contain an substring of length `i` ending in an element less than `x`, thus `smallest[i]` will be that element instead of `x`).
- In addition to this array, keep a binary search tree (BST) that maps elements to substring lengths (essentially the opposite of the array).

  When updating `smallest`, also remove the old element from the BST and insert the new one.

  (All of this so far were about substrings in the original array A, not the array post-removal C)
- Using this, we can find the longest substring `longestSSAfterB` in C ending at any element (directly following some B) by looking up the biggest element smaller than that element in the BST and adding 1 to that length.
- The longest substring in C ending at any given element will simply be the maximum of 1 + the longest substring ending in the previous element (if it's smaller, 0 otherwise) and `longestSSAfterB`.

  The longest substring in C will simply be the longest substring we found above.

All of this will take `O(n log n)`.

---

Example:

```
A = [3 2 5 7 1 2 8 1]
                   BST.floor(i)+1
        currentSS  longestSSAfterB  longestSSinC  smallest BST
A[0]=3  1          0+1=1            max(1,0+1)=1  [3]      [(3→1)]
A[1]=2  1          0+1=1            max(1,0+1)=1  [2]      [(2→1)]
A[2]=5  2          (2→1)->1+1=2     max(2,1+1)=2  [2,5]    [(2→1), (5→2)]
A[3]=7  3          (5→2)->2+1=3     max(3,2+1)=2  [2,5,7]  [(2→1), (5→2), (7→3)]
A[4]=1  1          0+1=1            max(1,0+1)=1  [1,5,7]  [(1→1), (5→2), (7→3)]
A[5]=2  2          (1→1)->1+1=2     max(2,1+1)=2  [1,2,7]  [(1→1), (2→2), (7→3)]
A[6]=8  3          (7→3)->3+1=4     max(4,2+1)=4  [1,2,7]  [(1→1), (2→2), (7→3)]
A[7]=1  1          0+1=1            max(1,0+1)=1  [1,5,7]  [(1→1), (5→2), (7→3)]

Longest substring = max(longestSSinC) = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two auxiliary arrays of length `n` - `noskip` and `skip`.

An element `noskip[i]` contains the length of the longest increasing substring ending at `i`, without cutting out anything from the original string. Compute this array in the first pass of the algorithm in O(n).

An element `skip[i]` contains the length of the longest increasing substring ending at `i`, with a skip of a single group in the middle. Compute this array in a second run of the algorithm by looking back at values of `noskip`, in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The highest value of `skip` array is the answer to your problem.

Here is how the two arrays would look for your input:

```
data:   3 2 5 7 1 2 8 1
noskip: 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1
skip:   1 1 2 3 1 2 4 1
```

When we look at `8`, we iterate back through `data`, looking for an element such that `j < i`, `data[j] < data[i]`, and `noskip[j]+1 > skip[i]`. The initial value of `skip[i]` is set to `skip[i-1]` if `data[i] > data[i-1]`, or `1` otherwise.

Here is a sample implementation in Java:

```
int[] data = new int[] {3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 8, 1};
int[] noskip = new int[data.length];
int[] skip = new int[data.length];
noskip[0] = 1;
for (int i = 1 ; i != skip.length ; i++) {
    noskip[i] = data[i] > data[i-1] ? noskip[i-1]+1 : 1;
}
skip[0] = 1;
int res = 1;
for (int i = 1 ; i != data.length ; i++) {
    skip[i] = data[i] > data[i-1] ? skip[i-1]+1 : 1;
    for (int j = i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--) {
        if (data[j] < data[i] && noskip[j]+1 > skip[i]) {
            skip[i] = noskip[j]+1;
        }
    }
    res = Math.max(res, skip[i]);
}
System.out.println(res);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cY45Zw)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't though much about the problem, but I think this `O(nlogn)` solution would work.

For A, maintain to arrays say `pref` and `suff`.

`pref[i]` contains the longest increasing subarray (LIS) you can create starting from `i`. Similarly `suff[i]` contains the LIS you can create ending at `i`.

They can be created in `O(n)`.

Then find the optimal combination of `(i,j)` such that `suff[i] + pref[j]` is maximum, `i<j and arr[i]<arr[j]`. This can be found by iterating through every `i`, and finding every `j` by storing the `pref` array as a bst.

---

For your example, `A = [3 2 5 7 1 2 8 1]`.

Then,

```
3 2 5 7 1 2 8 1 (arr)
1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 (suff)
1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 (pref)
```

Removing 1,2 as you said gives suff[3] + pref[6] = 3 + 1 = 4.